# Как изменить CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

После предикшена я получил CSV file

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'Id': test_data.Id,
                       'SalePrice': test_preds})
output.to_csv('submission.csv', index=False)
```

Но как мне сделать файл без заголовков Id и SalePrice - он сразу должен начинаться с этих двух значений:

```
1 0.3442
2 2.1312
и т.д.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь параметром [header=False](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

> **header** : bool or list of str, default True
>
> Write out the column names. If a list of strings is given it is
>   assumed to be aliases for the column names.
>
> Changed in version 0.24.0: Previously defaulted to False for Series.

```
output.to_csv('submission.csv', index=False, header=False)
```